# Obfuscate string - encode unicode with checksum - pseudocode

Tags: unicode, encoding, checksum, pseudocode

I want to obfuscate a string (more specifically a link) and the other side needs to decode it.

It doesn't have to be secure at all the original string just can't look like a link after encoding.

I plan to have something like a checksum flag in the encoded string to make sure it's an encoded string and not a random text.
An easy way would be something basic like base64 but I want to keep the encoded string short.

(Is it possible to use unicode characters for groups of alphabet characters to get a shorter string?)

I'm just asking for pseudocode or advice if that is possible.

Comment: Just rot13 it and swap `/` and `,` or something.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I have it at the moment. But I'm looking for a way to implement a check flag to make sure it's an encoded string.

Comment: If you're not concerned with security as you say, I wouldn't worry about it. Just look for `{encoded-protocol}:,,` in the beginning of the string for example. Although I'm not sure how you're transmitting these and what your use-case is

Comment: Define "shorter string".